# How do you set up *actual* displacement maps in eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, displacement

In eevee I put a texture into a displacement node, then that displacement into the material output displacement, which is what this site says is supposed to work, but unsurprisingly that doesn't. The shading/texture/display/view port/... w/e only acts as though it's the primitive Blender Render normal setting, not like an actual displacement modifier, which Blender Render does process correctly. How is this supposed to work for eevee?

Comment: Short answer: It doesn't. (As of yet). The only way to get displacement maps working in Eevee is by using a Displacement Modifier on top of either dense topology or a Multiresolution Modifier or a Subdivision Surface Modifier. For the "unsurprisingly doesn't work" part. It does certainly work. It just doesn't work as you expect it to work. In both cases you need enough vertices to get any good results.

Comment: I don't think you know what the word "unsurprisingly" means. It doesn't work in the exact way I expected it to fail. Vertex count isn't a problem, that is easily solved by a subsurf or multires modifier. As you just admitted yourself, the problem is that eevee intrinsically lacks the capacity to achieve the standard result.